# Cocos2d-x adding objects to isometric tilemap

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm making game with isometric map using cocos2d-x (it's something like age of empires game, but simpler). I have "default" map with resources, trees and so on and user should be able to place new objects (buildings) to the map. And there is a problem: z order of the objects. When I add new object, it goes over all tiles on the map:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2PFJ.png)

User-added building (farm) should not go over the tree because it's "behind" it. I'm adding new objects to the map as child sprites to tile map:

```
CCSprite* tmpCastle=CCSprite::create("castleMenu.png");
tmpCastle->setPosition(touchLocation);
tileMap->addChild(tmpCastle);
```

I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a project I developed few months back. That's how I solved it:

1- Calculate **z** dynamically based on their position.

2- Set anchor point to **ccp(0.5, 0)** (as most of the items start from center bottom e.g, Tree)

3- The object that has lesser **x** and **y** co-ords are the items above.

So add the following code after your sprites:

```
tmpCastle->setAnchorPoint(0.5, 0);

int z = (TILEMAP_WIDTH - tmpCastle->getPositionX()) + (TILEMAP_HEIGHT
- tmpCastle->getPositionY());
tmpCastle->setZOrder(z);
```